# Determining a custom set in the complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $A(z) , B(z^2)$ and $C(z^3)$ 3 points on the complex plane.
Determine the set of points $A(z)$ so that $ABC$ is a rectangular triangle.
I tried the solving it by cases and found that $z=-1 +iy  (y>0)$, but I'm not sure if its correct so can I get some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The squares of the sides of $\triangle ABC$ are:

$$
\begin{align}
AB^2=|z^2 -z|^2 &= |z|^2 |z-1|^2 \\
BC^2=|z^3-z^2|^2 &=|z|^4 |z-1|^2 \\
CA^2=|z-z^3|^2 &=|z|^2|z-1|^2|z+1|^2
\end{align}$$

Dividing by the common factor $|z|^2|z-1|^2\,$, it follows that the squares of the  sides are proportional to $c^2=1\,$, $a^2=|z|^2\,$, and $b^2=|z+1|^2=(z+1)(\bar z+1)=|z|^2+2 \operatorname{Re}(z)+1\,$.

By [Pythagoras' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) the triangle is a right triangle iff one of those squares is equal to the sum of the other two, which leaves $3$ cases to consider:

- right angle at $A\,$ $\iff a^2=b^2+c^2$

$$\require{cancel}
\cancel{|z|^2}=\cancel{|z|^2}+2 \operatorname{Re}(z)+1 + 1 \;\;\iff\;\; \boxed{\operatorname{Re}(z) = -1}
$$

- right angle at $B\,$ $\iff b^2=c^2+a^2$

$$
\cancel{|z|^2}+2 \operatorname{Re}(z)+\bcancel{1} = \bcancel{1} + \cancel{|z|^2} \;\;\iff\;\; \boxed{\operatorname{Re}(z) = 0}
$$

- right angle at $C\,$ $\iff c^2=a^2+b^2$

$$
\cancel{1} = |z|^2 + |z|^2+2 \operatorname{Re}(z)+\cancel{1} \;\;\iff\;\; |z|^2 = -\operatorname{Re}(z) \;\;\iff\;\; \boxed{\left|z+\frac{1}{2}\right|^2=\frac{1}{4}}$$

Therefore the solution set is the union of two vertical lines and a circle in the complex plane.

Comment: But if the right angle is at C wouldn't that mean: Arg((b-c)/(a-c))=π/2 [2π]? If it does then I get Arg(z)=π/2 [2π] which means z is a pure imaginary number. Is there something wrong with my assumption?

Comment: @user505452 `if the right angle is at C ...` then $\require{cancel} \pm \frac{\pi}{2}=\arg \frac{z^2-z^3}{z-z^3}$ $=\arg \frac{z^\bcancel{2}\cancel{(1-z)}}{\bcancel{z}\cancel{(1-z)}(1+z)}$ $=\arg \frac{z}{1+z}$ whose locus is a circle. The case that results in $\arg z = \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ is when the right angle is at $B$, not $C$, and in that case the locus is the imaginary axis $\operatorname{Re}(z) = 0$ indeed.